# Meteor tutorial "simple-todos" shows error in Firefox "Cross-Origin Request Blocked", but works in Chrome

Tags: firefox, meteor, cross-domain

I'm new to Meteor and am following this tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

It works fine in Chrome, but on Firefox I get this error:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ddp--7177-ingaborg_test.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=f9hnt5jlkk. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

You can try it here: http://ingaborg_test.meteor.com/

I am running Linux Mint 17.1.

Does anybody have any idea what is the problem? All I have done is follow the tutorial exactly.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: When you are on your website at http://ingaborg_test.meteor.com/, the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol. The request blocked in your case is very important because it's the browser that try to etablish a DDP connection with the server, that's why the page does not load on your firefox. You need to understand why your meteor application use this domain.

Comment: But, I do not control this domain, it is the Meteor test domain and I do not know why it is requesting data from a different domain - or why it works in Chrome but not Firefox? - or if everybody else who does this tutorial and uses meteor.com to deploy it has this problem, or if not, what have they done different?